# Html и CSS рамка вокруг фоновой картинки

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Короче у меня фоновое изображения есть и я прикрепил его в группу. но вокруг него рамка вот код с HTML И CSS

```css
.body {
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "OpenSansRegular", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "OpenSansLight", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: em(43);
}

.h2 {
  font-size: em(34);
}

.h3,
h4 {
  font-family: "OpenSansSemibold", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: em(17);
}

h4 {
  font-size: em(15);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.main-head {
  background-image: url(img/bg_top.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mnu_line {
  padding-top: 48px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">
  <div class="cinteiner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mnu_line" clearfix>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Ovk Stroy"></a>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        <div class="col-md2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: точка перед `body` в css

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакой рамки, то что на скрине - отступы, избавиться от них можно обнулением вот только уберите точку перед `body` (если это стили для тега `body`, а не для тега с классом `.body`):

```css
body { 
  font-size: 14px; 
  min-width: 320px; 
  position: relative; 
  line-height: 1.6em; 
  font-family: "OpenSansRegular", sans-serif; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  color:#222; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0; 
} 

.h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  font-family: "OpenSansLight", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: normal; 
} 
.h1 { font-size: em(43); } 
.h2 { font-size: em(34); } 
.h3, h4 { font-family: "OpenSansSemibold", sans-serif; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-size: em(17); 
} 
h4{ font-size: em(15); } 
.hidden { display: none; } 
.main-head { 
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png); 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: top center; 
  min-height: 100vh; 
  border: none; 
  box-shadow: none; 
  padding: 0; margin:0; 
} .mnu_line { padding-top:48px; } .logo { display: block; width: 100px; } 
.logo img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="main-head">
      <div class="cinteiner">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="mnu_line" clearfix>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>            
            <a href="#" class="logo">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Ovk Stroy">
            </a>        
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md2"></div>    
          </div>   
        </div> 
      </div>   
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```